# Why does my java applet work with some images and not others?

Tags: java, image, applet, awt

I have an applet, and I'm trying to draw an image in it.  If I set the image file to one of two test files, the image displays correctly.  However, it will not draw any of the images generated by rotsprite.  I thought at first it was a file-type issue, as the original two are .png and the rotsprite output is .bmp, but when I used GIMP to export the bitmaps to png I get the same result.  I'm not getting any errors or console messages, just that the image won't draw.

These loops are in my `init()` method to initialize an arraylist of sprites for my rocket.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        Image temp = getImage(base, "./data/rahkeht_sprite_0" + i + ".png");
        rahkehtImage.add(temp);
    }
for (int i = 10; i < 37; i++) {
        Image temp = getImage(base, "./data/rahkeht_sprite_" + i + ".png");
        rahkehtImage.add(temp);
    }
```

These are my `update()` and `paint()` methods.

```
public void update(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(rahkehtImage.get(rahkeht.getAngle()), 0, 0, this);
}
```

I know the path and file names are correct, because I've stepped through with a watch on my image list, and, like I said before, I can get it to load two other test images in the same directory.

[image]

Below is a complete class exhibiting the problem.  I have included an example of an image that does work as well as one like the image above that does not.

```
package Main;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable{

private Image image, temp, temp2;
private Graphics second;
private URL base;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true){
        repaint();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void init(){
    setSize(480,800);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    Frame frame = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("StackOverflow Code");
    try{
        base = getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    //won't draw converted png
    temp = getImage(base, "./data/rahkeht_sprite_01.png");

    //will draw this one
    temp2 = getImage(base, "./data/character.png");

}

public void start() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void update(Graphics g){
    if (image == null) {
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);     
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(temp, 1, 1, this); //won't draw
    g.drawImage(temp2, 300, 300, this); //will draw
}
```

}

Overriding the update method is not breaking the drawing, but http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/ui/drawing/update.html provides a pretty good explanation of why I'm overriding the update method.

Comment: have you tried it with JPGs instead of PNGs?

Comment: No I have not tried jpgs

Comment: Can you embed one of these problem PNG in the question?  Note that PNG is AFAIR, a container format.  Meaning it might be encoded using a number of different formats.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  2) Is this using Swing or AWT? 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: `public void update(Graphics g) {..`  In 10+ years of coding Java, including many custom painting examples, I've never once needed to override the `update` method.  Why do you think you need to?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, and I'll soon need to remove it:**  I can successfully load that image direct from imgur.com using the source seen below.  Does this source work for you?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

class ImageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRSbY.png");
        final Image img = ImageIO.read(url);

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```